# File is getting really big need to separate data into another file but also need to use private variables. How can I achieve this correctly?

Tags: c++, file

So I have a huge (legacy) file, call it HUGE.cxx. I'm adding new feature, but the file is getting even more big. I tried to create different classes for different jobs, but for some task I need to access the private variables. Here is a rough draft of what is going on

```
//HUGE.h
class Huge{
  NewFeature object;
  //...more stuff
};

//HUGE.cxx
Huge::Huge(){    
  //imagine object keeps track of id->func callback
  object.on('uniqueID1', boost::bind(&HUGE::onID1Clicked,this));
}
void Huge::onID1Clicked()const{ return satisfiesSomeCondition(); }
//called internally when user right clicks
void Huge::createPopup()const{
   for itr = object.begin to end  
      callback = itr->second;
      //if satisfies condition add to popupmenu
      if(callback()) addToPopupMenu( itr->first );
}
//event handler
void Huge::event(id){
  //oh uniqueID1 was clicked as a menu item in right click
  case 'uniqueID1': doSpecificFunctionality(); break;
}
```

so you see, I have some dependencies going there, but the file is so big and so are my changes. Do you have any advice on further separating out into more files. I know I can add a friend declaration to Huge file and add another class, but wanted to avoid that option if possible.

Comment: Do you want it split into separate files, or separate compilation units? If it's the former... you could just split it into separate files and #include them from HUGE.cxx. Horrible, but would make the individual files smaller.

Comment: @icabod thanks for your help, I think that is what I will end up doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you actually need a major refactor, separating concerns into their proper places.

But, to solve your immediate problem, there's no particular reason why all of `Huge` needs to be defined in `Huge.cxx`. You can split the function definitions into separate files, as long as every function is defined *somewhere*.

You might end up with:

- `Huge.h`
- `Huge-private.cxx`
- `Huge-public.cxx`

Or however it makes sense to split your code.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go for now. Awesome thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

As long as all the `.cxx` files include `HUGE.h`, and all the used functions are declared there (which should be the case), you can split up the implementation in as many `.cxx` files as you want. You could even put each function into its own file.

To call a function, the compiler only needs to see the prototype from `HUGE.h`. Later, when all the compiled files are linked together, the linker will combine the code from the different object files as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Serious advice: Learn about refactoring (http://refactoring.com) and design patterns.

Without seeing the *whole* thing, it is hard or impossible to tell you something really specific. You probably need an arsenal of refactoring ammunition. For some parts, extracting methods and merging common functionality is the right thing; for other parts, dependency inversion may be the tool of choice.

Beyond some critical mass of mud, a (clean) rewrite might be the sanest and most profitable thing to do: Begin with defining what the input and the expected output is (during that, write tests).

Comment: File has over 12k lines of code, and no one wants to risk breakage. So I can't really do this as an option, otherwise would have been my first choice.

Comment: Refcatoring the whole file is just not an option right now, that is all. wish it was.

Comment: Ah, so you really meant splitting it up literally? Okay, know your pain. Then the other answers might fit your need better.